# What is the difference between raise and except?

Tags: python

What is the point of raising an exception when we have except to handle exceptions? Is it because raising an exception allows you to create your own defined exceptions?

```
except:
  raise ZeroDivisionError
```

vs.

```
except ZeroDivisionError:
  #code
```

Comment: `What is the point of raising an exception when we have except to handle exceptions?` You can't handle a exception which wasn't raised.

Comment: `except` is how you handle an exception that some other code signalled. `raise` is how you signal an exception yourself. It's like asking what the difference is between making a phone call and answering the phone.

Comment: In `except` you usually handle exceptions, you normally don't raise other exceptions. I guess you got the above code from a source example, right? Probably the code with the `raise` inside the `except` clause is just to make a more general exception more descriptive. So it's not handling the exception, but replaceing the exception so it can be handled by the caller of the code.

Comment: Much like the difference between 'give' and 'take'

Comment: Your question is the equivalent of asking what the point of throwing a ball is, when you can just *catch* balls instead. How do you think the ball might have come to be in a position to *be* catched? `raise` throws balls, `except` catches balls.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Perhaps it helps if you think of exceptions as *tossing and catching balls*. One person throws a ball, someone else catches the ball. It's just that some people want to only catch baseballs, while other people only want to catch basketballs, and if someone throws a golfball, perhaps noone is around to catch those..

In that analogy, look at these three snippets of syntax:

- `raise SomeException:` throws an exception (a specific type of ball, like throwing only tennis balls).
- `except:` catches *all* exceptions (regardless of type). This is the equivalent of someone catching all ball types, no matter what. If you can throw them a billiard ball, they'll catch it.
- `except SomeException:` on the other hand only catches a *specific* type of exception (like someone that'll only catch baseballs and will ignore anything else).

Then, the following code

```
try:
    # ...
except:
    raise ZeroDivisionError
```

does **two, separate things**. First, it catches **all** exceptions. And when it has caught an exception, it then *raises a new exception*.

It's as if someone is standing in a sportsfield, and catches basketballs, baseballs, tennisballs, billiard balls, anything you throw at it, but *every time they catch a ball* they then will, without fail, throw a golfball at the referee. Nothing else, only golfballs.

That's not the case in this example:

```
try:
    # ...
except ZeroDevisionError:
    # ...
```

That's someone only *catching* golfballs. They are not throwing anything, they are *only catching*, and only golfballs. Basketballs, baseballs and tennisballs are ignored. That's not the same thing as catching everything, and no throwing is going on.

Finally:

```
raise SomeException
```

can be used in any Python code. Code is allowed to throw balls if they feel the need to. You don't need to be catching balls at the same time.

Exceptions are used to *break out of the normal flow*. For example, you can count on the `int()` function *only ever returning an integer value*. When it *can't* return a value, because something is wrong, it'll raise an exception instead. That way you know it couldn't return a proper integer, because things were wrong somehow. `int("Hello world!")` can't return an integer value (what would the value be?) so a `ValueError` exception is raised. When you write your own code, you'll also come across situations where you can't produce a normal, valid response either, so that's when you'd use `raise` yourself.

And catching *all* exceptions, with a blanket `except:`, is *usually not what you want to do*. I call that playing Pokemon, but you should not play Pokemon when writing good Python code. Because catching all exceptions means you also catch `KeyboardInterrupt` and `MemoryError`, things that you normally would want to let the program just end. And you'd catch simple errors caused by programming mistakes. You want to catch specific exceptions only, *usually*.

Comment: Thanks, this analogy helps a lot. But for the first example, it catches all exceptions, including things like KeyboardInterrupt and MemoryError right? And then it would raise another exception, maybe something that's not related to the exception that was caught. So would this code ever be useful, since you mentioned using except: is usually not what you want to do?

Comment: @pastacompany: a blanket `except:` that raises a new exception does have specialised uses, usually in command-line tools. The `pydoc` tool uses this to signal a failed import, the new exception raised documents what failed, and further up that new exception is caught and turned into a readable error message.

Answer (score 5):

except is used within a try-except statement, meaning there is an error within your code that caused this exception to be raised. Raise is used for signaling an exception that you want to point out. An example:

```
for x in range(5):
  if x < 3:
    raise Exception('x is less than 3')
  else:
    print('x is 3 or higher')
```

In other words, your code will not be broken/will still run even if you don't signal your own exception, whereas if you were to remove a try-except statement from your code, and exception would be raised because of some error (ValueError, AssertionError, etc.). You cannot raise a system exception as you do in the first section of code you posted, only the second will work for properly dealing with error statements issued by python itself.

Comment: What is the difference if I were to remove/keep a try-except statement after raise Exception('x is less than 3')?